# C++ Pointer to an Array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

Been having some trouble with a pointer to an array and passing it to a function. Whenever I pass the pointer only the first element is passed and I can't access other elements in debug.

```
Type* variable[2];

void myFunction(Type* var);
```

Comment: You have to pass in the size alongside the pointer.  There's no way around this, except for using [`array_view`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3851.pdf) which may be included in a future STL

Comment: `variable` is an array of pointers, not pointer to array.  To leave `variable` unchanged, `myFunction`should be redeclared to take a `Type **` argument,

Comment: Why is `variable` an array of `Type*`, is `Type` polymorphic?

Comment: @fredoverflow, Because that's what's in his declaration: `variable` is a "array with `2` elements" whose type is "pointer to `Type`".  Isn't it?

Comment: That is an array of pointers. A pointer to an array of 2 `Type`s would be `Type (*variable)[2]`. A pointer to the array in your question (`&variable`) would have type `Type* (*)[2]`. A pointer to its first element (`&variable[0]`) has type `Type**`.

Comment: @Paulo1205 I was asking OP why he uses `Type*[2]` instead of simply `Type[2]`.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) instead, it carries around such details for you.

```
std::array<Type*, 2> variable;

void myFunction(std::array<Type*, 2>&);
```

Comment: You can't have arbitrary length arrays with `std::array`.

Comment: @Sorin What does that have to do with the question?

Comment: It works in this particular case because you know the array size at compile time. That's usually not the case. It's not clear from the question if the example is just an example or the actual use case. `std::vector` would be more general.

Answer (score 0):

Usually when it is being said a pointer to an array then it means the pointer to the first element of the array.

Elements of this array

```
Type* variable[2];
```

have type `Type *`

So to pass pointer to the first element of the array to the function the function should be declared like

```
void myFunction( Type* *var);
```

or

```
void myFunction( Type* var[]);
```

These declarations are equivalent because implicitly the parameter is adjusted to pointer to an object of type `T*`.

You can imagine it the folloing way. If you have an array of type U

```
U a[N];
```

then the "pointer to the array" will look like

```
U *p = a;
```

If U in turn is defined like

```
typedef T* U;
```

then you have

```
T*  a[N];
T* *p = a;
```

Strictly speaking pointer to your array will look like

```
Type* variable[2];
Type * ( *p )[2] = &variable;
```

However usually as I pointed above pointer to an array means the pointer to the first element of the array.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in a comment, `variable` is an array of pointers, not pointer to array.

To leave `variable` unchanged, `myFunction` should be redeclared to take a `Type **` argument, so that you can call it as `myFunction(variable)`.

However, when you call it like this, the type of the function argument is no longer an array, but a pointer (in an expression other than a declaration or as operands to `sizeof` or unary `&`, the array decays to a pointer to the the type of the elements), so you lose the information on the array size.

To fix that, the classic C-style solution is to add an extra argument to the function, so that you can tell it what is the number of arguments.

```
void myFunction(Type **arr_to_ptrs, size_t ptr_count);
```

Still with C, if you guarantee that you'll always call the function with an argument that is declared as an array or something that resolves to an array at language level (as opposed to a pointer that might be used as an array through dynamic allocation), you can define a macro to calculate the number of elements.

```
#define myFunction_1arg(x) myFunction(x, sizeof x/sizeof x[0])
```

> Again, whatever you use as an argument to `myFunction_1arg` macro must be an array at language level.  Using a pointer as its argument is likely to break you program.

With C++, almost every use of native arrays can be more generally and safely addressed with `std::vector`, and less generally with `std::array`.

However, if you really want to stick to native arrays, you can still use some of the features of C++.  The program below might give you an idea.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstddef>

const char a[]="ab";                     // array
const char *ap[]={"aa", "bb", nullptr};  // array of pointers
const char (*pa)[3]=&a;                  // pointer to array of three elements

// This function takes an array (by reference).
template <typename T, size_t sz> void f(T (&arr)[sz]){
  std::cout << "array-templated f(): addr=" << static_cast<const void *>(arr) << ", size=" << sz << '\n';
}

// This function takes a pointer (by lvalue reference).
template <typename T> void f(T *const &arr){
  std::cout << "lvalue-ref-pointer-templated f(): addr=" << static_cast<const void *>(arr) << ", unspecified size\n";
}

// This function takes a pointer (by rvalue reference).
template <typename T> void f(T *const &&arr){
  std::cout << "rvalue-ref-pointer-templated f(): addr=" << static_cast<const void *>(arr) << ", unspecified size\n";
}

// This function takes a pointer and its size (by value).
template <typename T> void f(T *arr, size_t sz){
  std::cout << "pointer-templated f(): addr=" << static_cast<const void *>(arr) << ", manual size=" << sz << "\n";
}


int main(){
  f(a);
  f(ap);
  f(pa);
  std::cout << '\n';

  f(0+a);
  f(0+ap);
  f(0+pa);
  std::cout << '\n';

  f(a, 1);     // You can lie here, but you shouldn't
  f(ap, 10);   // You can lie here, but you shouldn't
  f(pa, 100);  // You can lie here, but you shouldn't
  std::cout << '\n';

  f(0+a, 1);     // You can lie here, but you shouldn't
  f(0+ap, 10);   // You can lie here, but you shouldn't
  f(0+pa, 100);  // You can lie here, but you shouldn't
  std::cout << '\n';

  auto *p=a;
  auto *pp=ap;
  auto *pa2=pa; // pa2 and pa are the same type: pa is already a pointer
  f(p);
  f(pp);
  f(pa2);
  std::cout << '\n';

  f(p, 1);      // You can lie here, but you shouldn't
  f(pp, 10);    // You can lie here, but you shouldn't
  f(pa2, 100);  // You can lie here, but you shouldn't
  std::cout << '\n';

  f(0+p, 1);      // You can lie here, but you shouldn't
  f(0+pp, 10);    // You can lie here, but you shouldn't
  f(0+pa2, 100);  // You can lie here, but you shouldn't
}
```

The output for this program is somewhat like the one shown below.

```
array-templated f(): addr=0x40106d, size=3
array-templated f(): addr=0x602070, size=3
lvalue-ref-pointer-templated f(): addr=0x40106d, unspecified size

rvalue-ref-pointer-templated f(): addr=0x40106d, unspecified size
rvalue-ref-pointer-templated f(): addr=0x602070, unspecified size
rvalue-ref-pointer-templated f(): addr=0x40106d, unspecified size

pointer-templated f(): addr=0x40106d, manual size=1
pointer-templated f(): addr=0x602070, manual size=10
pointer-templated f(): addr=0x40106d, manual size=100

pointer-templated f(): addr=0x40106d, manual size=1
pointer-templated f(): addr=0x602070, manual size=10
pointer-templated f(): addr=0x40106d, manual size=100

lvalue-ref-pointer-templated f(): addr=0x40106d, unspecified size
lvalue-ref-pointer-templated f(): addr=0x602070, unspecified size
lvalue-ref-pointer-templated f(): addr=0x40106d, unspecified size

pointer-templated f(): addr=0x40106d, manual size=1
pointer-templated f(): addr=0x602070, manual size=10
pointer-templated f(): addr=0x40106d, manual size=100

pointer-templated f(): addr=0x40106d, manual size=1
pointer-templated f(): addr=0x602070, manual size=10
pointer-templated f(): addr=0x40106d, manual size=100
```